# How to set up proper object teardown when using GCD and calling back to main thread?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Consider this setup:

Object A creates object B for doing some work, and sets itself as B's delegate to be informed of work progress.

B does some work with GCD blocks, and signals back to A with the delegate method about work completion. A wants to tear down (release) B upon work completion.

In code terms:

Object A:

```
B *b = [[B alloc] init];
b.delegate = self;
[b doSomeWork];
- (void) didSomeWorkFromB:(B *)b {
    [b release];
    b = nil;
}
```

Object B:

```
- (void) doSomeWork {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        doSomeWork();

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Work is complete.");
            [self.delegate didSomeWorkFromB:self];
        });

    });
}
```

PROBLEM: calling [b release] inside object A causes a crash. I think it's because the dispatch queue/background code is still running when A tries to release B.

QUESTION: how do I properly set up the objects and signaling in this case, to make sure that A only destroys B when all the background work has been completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bogus question. It actually works as expected and the code above does not crash. The crash was caused by some unrelated code.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, that the code works as is. But it is unnecessarily complicated.

You can just have B's `doSomeWork` retain itself (either by explicitly calling `[self retain]` and `[self release]` in `doSomeWork` or just by referencing `self` in the `dispatch_async` block, which will retain it for us), and let `A` clean up immediately after the invocation of `doSomeWork`, and therefore no further cleanup is required in `didSomeWorkFromB`.

This pattern is very common in iOS. For example, if you look at many common implementations of  `NSURLConnection`, since it retains itself while the connection is downloading, and releases itself once the connection is done, we often don't both keeping a reference to the connection and cleaning it up in `connectionDidFinishLoading`. Just let the magic of reference counting memory management take care of everything for you.

In `A`:

```
- (void) test
{
    B *b = [[B alloc] init];
    b.delegate = self;
    [b doSomeWork];
    [b release];    // you could also autorelease above, but I just wanted to make it more explicit for the purposes of the demonstration
}

- (void) didSomeWorkFromB:(B *)b
{
    // [b release]; // don't need to release it ... we already did
    // b = nil;     // certainly don't need to nil local reference ... this does nothing useful in any scenario
}
```

In `B`:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    // let's log this so we can see when it's deallocated

    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) doSomeWork
{
    // [self retain];  // you could manually retain if you want

    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        sleep(10);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Work is complete.");

            [self.delegate didSomeWorkFromB:self];

            // [self release]; // and if you manually retained, you'd manually release, too
        });
    });
}
```

In my opinion, this approach (of having A `release` B immediately after calling `doSomeWork`) is more robust, more closely coordinating the balancing cleanup of the object. I also think this puts you in better stead as you contemplate an eventual shift to ARC.